# how do i compile/link test cases (googleTest) using cmake to the code bundled up in shared library?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

My project is organized like this:

- cpp

  - main.cpp (calls code from `dataStructures/` and `common/`)
  - CMakeLists.txt (*topmost* CMakeLists file)
  - build
  - test

    - main.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - common

      - CMakeLists.txt
      - include
      - src
    - googletest
    - build
  - common

    - CMakeLists.txt (should be responsible for building common shared library)
    - include

      - utils.h
    - src

      - utils.cpp
    - build

`build\` directories contain the built target. The actual code can be seen here: https://github.com/brainydexter/PublicCode/tree/master/cpp

I'm able to build `shared` libraries for the actual code ( like `common`). Now, I'd like to test it using GoogleTest. So, I created a `test` directory and put the test code in there (what I have in the repo is just a sample, more like hello world to get the build system up and working. I will be adding more test cases later on).

**I need some help in triggering the tests from the topmost CMakeLists.txt**. I'm not sure how to do this. In `test`, CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.2)

add_subdirectory(googletest/googletest)
include_directories(googletest/googletest/include)

add_subdirectory(common)

enable_testing()

add_executable(testCpp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testCpp gtest gtest_main )
```

Do I need to add anything else to enable tests in `test/common` ?

`test/common/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(testCommon ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(testCommon cppCommon)
```

**I'm not sure if the target should be executable here or a library that the google test framework can consume ?** I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to test the code that is in the shared library, you have to create an executable file with exactly this main https://github.com/brainydexter/PublicCode/blob/master/cpp/test/main.cpp, all your testsuites and link it against your library.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [FindGTest](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindGTest.html) module helpful. Since the location of gtest is fixed, you can do something along these lines to find it:

```
set (GTEST_ROOT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest)
find_package (GTest required)
```

As for whether you need an executable, this module defines the `GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES` variable, so that when you link your tests, you simply need to do:

```
target_link_libraries(testCommon ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES})
```

The resulting binary will use the default gtest main function.